# Problem with installation. Atleast 5.9gb free space required

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I tried to install Ubuntu 13 alongside Windows with a bootable disc. However, it doesn't check the "at least 5.9gb free space" and I cannot click the "Continue" button.

What I did:

- I kept 20gb of free space in local disk C.
- I kept 15gb of unallocated space.
- De-fragmented the whole drive.
- Checked the bootable disc for errors.

Some specifications:

- Windows 8.1 pro is installed
- 160 GB hard disk
- 2x 1 GB RAM
- 3 local drives
- 15 GB unallocated space

Is there anything I should do to make the installation work?

Answer (score 0):

Before running the Ubuntu installer, first combine all the free spaces into one. From the combined space create a new ext4 partition.(You have to do this all through gparted partition editor)

Now run the Ubuntu installer and install Ubuntu on newly created ext4 partition by choosing **something else** option.

Comment: I'm new to this. Can't I install without trying to combine. I like the way it is.

Comment: you can also create an ext4 partition from anyone of the freespace 20gb or 15 gb.

Comment: I tried to do this. But gparted doesn't show my hard disk on the list. Instead it is showing USB flash drive only. I used gparted live 0.18 & Tuxboot 0.6

Comment: select your HDD from the drop-down list appears on the top right corner of your gparted partition editor.

Comment: I checked it there. Only one in the drop down(USB flash drive)

Comment: did you able to boot into windows?

Comment: Yes & I'm posting from it right now.

Comment: Boot from ubuntu live dis, select try Ubuntu option on startup. Open up the terminal and then run `lsblk` command. Post it's output to pastebin.com.Finally provide the link here.

Comment: While i was trying it again, i saw this on black screen . I think this is thing that causing the errors. Here it is [ 0.1256721] pci 0000:06:05.0: BAR 3: error updating (0x00a061 ! 0x00a041)